# spring data neo4j crud - many optional param?

Tags: spring, neo4j, crud

I use `Spring-data-neo4j` with one `CrudRepository`

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends GraphRepository<Person> {}
```

I have a Html form with 3 inputs FirstName, Name, Age, so I have possible a multiple criteria choose : `All, FirstName, FirstName + Name, FirstName + Age etc....`

I would like to make a "multiple criteria find" with Map or other stuff. Is it possible?

I try this in my CRUD:

```
List<Person> findByFirstnameAndNameAndAge(String firstname, String name, int age);
```

but it's not work if one or all parameters is null.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a map and a @Query annotation

```
@Query("MATCH (u:Person) WHERE u.name = {param}.name OR u.age = {param}.age RETURN u")
List<Person> findDynamic(@Param("param") Map params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Michael Hunger Thank you for your response. It's not exactly what I expected but you delivered me some fine search stuff

finally I do this :

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.map.HashedMap;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

(...)

@Autowired
private EventRepository eventRepository; //@Repository extends GraphRepository<Event>

(...)

public List<Event> findByDynamicParam(HashedMap params) {
    String query = "match (event)-[:user]-(user), (event)-[:action]-(action)";
    if (!params.isEmpty()) {
        query += " where";
    }
    if (params.containsKey("actionId")) {
        query += " id(action) = {actionId} and";
    }
    if (params.containsKey("userId")) {
        query += " id(user) = {userId} and";
    }
    if (!params.isEmpty()) {
        query = query.substring(0, query.length() - 4);
    }
    query += " return (event)";
    return Lists.newArrayList(eventRepository.query(query, params));
}
```

client's caller :

```
HashedMap params = new HashedMap();
if (actionId != null) {
    params.put("actionId", actionId);
}
if (userId != null) {
    params.put("actionId", userId);
}
List<Event> events = eventService.findByDynamicParam(params);
```

What do you think? Is it possible to optimize this function?

Regards

Olivier from Paris